# How UNSET nested attribute?

Tags: arangodb, aql

I have such document:

```
{
  "name": "FirstObj",
  "attributes": {
    "my_attributes/601890": {
      "value": "Hellow World",
      "id": "my_attributes/601890",
      "name": "TEstAttr",
      "myAttribute": "my_attributes/601890",
      "_class": "MyAttributeValue"
    }
  },
  "_class": "MyObj"
}
```

I cannot write AQL query which unsets `"myAttribute": "my_attributes/601890"`. So i want to get such final document:

```
  {
  "name": "FirstObj",
  "attributes": {
    "my_attributes/601890": {
      "value": "Hellow World",
      "id": "my_attributes/601890",
      "name": "TEstAttr",
      "_class": "MyAttributeValue"
    }
  },
  "_class": "MyObj"
}
```

Note, field `attributes` is object like key-value.(`my_attributes/601890: {}`) The field will be huge in the future

Comment: `The field will be huge in the future` sounds like a potential data model flaw if you mean thousands of sub-attributes reaching megabytes of payload. Consider to use multiple documents, possibly in multiple collections so that mutations can be done quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set the value to `null` and set the options `keepNull` to `false` to remove the field during the update.

```
For item in collection
    UPDATE item 
    WITH {attributes: {"my_attributes/601890": {myAttribute: null}} } 
    IN collection 
    OPTIONS { keepNull: false }
```

Comment: The attribute key `my_attributes/601890` needs to be wrapped in quote marks, otherwise you get a syntax error because of the forward slash.